# Cannot read property '_id' of undefined - mongodb

Tags: ios, mongodb

I am beginner to iOS and i want to integrate mongo stitch to my project. 
But unfortunately when i tried to create a collection (after creating cluster and application) i got the following error on console.

[I have attached the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wsqA.png)

Sorry if it's a silly question, but, i am beginner so help needed.

Comment: You'll have to show some code. Otherwise nobody can say anything.

Comment: i didn't write any code yet.
https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/getting-started/todo-ios/
i am following this tutorial

Comment: If it is a problem with some service other people have made then you probably need to contact their customer support